# Needleman wunsch algorithm

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am currently building an app which decodes a DNA sequence and outputs the RNA and protein sequence.I am trying to extend this to be able to align two protein sequences based on the needleman wunsch algorithm; but unfortunately am not able to do so in "Visual Basic". As i am from a non coding background and this is my first attempt at coding anything so it would be of great help if you could drive my ship to dock.

Answer (score 0):

There are some implementations of this algorithm available online, like this: http://kunuk.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/dynamic-programming-example-with-c-using-needleman-wunsch-algorithm/ - you can use it in your program.